# Visual Studio 2015 autoformatting multiple namespace on a single line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, format, autoformatting

In Visual Studio 2015 for native C++.
I want to write the following, keeping both namespace A and B on a single line, to receive a single indent for the namespace block.

```
namespace A { namespace B {    
  class
  {
    ....
  }    
 }// end B
}// end A
```

The problem is that as soon as I auto format (CTRL K-D), Visual Studio reformat this to

> ```
> namespace A 
> { 
>   namespace B 
>   {   
>     class
>     {
>       ....
>     }    
>   } //end B
> } //end A
> ```

**Question** How can I make sure Visual Studio's auto format according to the first example above?

(I have tried to find the correct settings but not been successful)
I need to be C++11/14 compliant so `namespace A::B` is not a solution for me.

Comment: I once "worked" through all the formatting options to customize VS2013 quite good to my personal favors. Concerning your namespace issue, I would like have it exactly as described by you (except for the indentation inside of namespaces). I couldn't find any option to specify it. Whenever the auto-formatting becomes effective, the `namespace`s (and corresponding right braces) are "stacked" what I don't like at all. I've no solution except to prevent (or reverse) the auto-formatting whenever it bothers me. Sorry, that I cannot help. But I feel with you... ;-)

Comment: Not really helpful to you, but with C++17, you won't have to worry about it anymore

Comment: Switch to VS2017 and use nested namespace syntax like `namespace A::B`

Comment: @VTT namespace A::B is C++17, I need to be C++11/14 compliant. I will add this to the question to make it clear.